# Grails 2.3 Export plugin loosing the value

Tags: grails

1- I have this(TrabajoGrado is a Domain Object):

```
TrabajoGrado.list(params)
```

2- Before that line, I am doing this:

```
def tg = TrabajoGrado.findAll("from TrabajoGrado as b where "+query)
```

I need to replace the TrabajoGrado.list(params) with the new list that "tg" has. I tried this:

```
Instead of: TrabajoGrado.list(params)
Tried:      tg
```

This is happening because I need to export that list (export plugin 1.5 grails) and the [plugin example](http://grails.org/plugin/export) has this line:

```
exportService.export(params.exportFormat, response.outputStream, TrabajoGrado.list(params), fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
```

The file is empty when I use tg and has all the records when I use TrabajoGrado.list(params)

I have a form (post) that fills up the list "tg", but for some reason when I click:

```
<a class="excel" href="./reportes?exportFormat=excel&extension=xls"><g:img dir="images" file="docIcons/excel.png" /> EXCEL</a>
```

The tg gets null.

Can someone point me the mistake? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know that your query is returning results into `tg`?

Comment: When I submit the post action it does retrieve results, when I click the link it goes null

Comment: How you build your `query` variable?